# Selenium IDE custom formats and custom commands

Tags: selenium, command, format, selenium-ide

Is it possible to create a custom command in Selenium IDE using user-extensions.js and having it be able to change itself to a custom export format and if so, how?

I'm going to be using Selenium IDE to record tests which will be exported in a completely custom Java format to be run as part of a fully automated testing system. The format is NOT JUnit but rather each test is its own class and is loaded dynamically based on input to the system as a whole.

What I am wanting to do is create a custom command in the Selenium IDE called "takeScreenshot" which will map to a static takeScreenshot() method in my system when using Export As.

For example:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import tests.TestHarness;

public class SomeTestCase {

private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;

    public SomeTestCase(WebDriver driver) {
        baseUrl = "http://www.example.com/";
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void doTest() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        TestHarness.takeScreenshot();
        //Another command
        //Another command
        TestHarness.takeScreenshot();
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a program called [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) you can take a screen shot when you make the test and then compare it to the image it takes when you run the test.